# When is the Class-Path attribute in a Jar file examined and used

Tags: java, classpath, manifest

I have an academic question for which I don't find the appropriated documentatino from Sun/Oracle.

I have a set of Jar files and the java vm is started like this:

```
java -cp one.jar:two.jar:helper.jar my.company.project.Main
```

As you can see I don't use the *-jar* option but give a classpath. 
The *helper.jar* only has a manifest file defining a Class-Path containing the remaining jar files that are needed.

As I'm not using the *-jar* command line option I'm wondering if that manifest Class-Path is evaluated and used. (Yes, I know what *-jar* does, I know what Main-Class is for and I know how to use the Class-Path in conjunction with *-jar*. I only don't know if it works **without** using *-jar*)

Or to clarify my question: does it work reliable and is somewhere documented in an official Sun/Oracle document?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know both `Main-Class` **and** `Class-Path` are used **only** when `-jar` is used.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I am afraid you are wrong. The Class-Path from the Manifest is also used without the -jar switch. See my answer below. It's easy to build a small sample with two classes and two JAR files to prove it.

Comment: Thank you @JoachimSauer for pointing out that I made a mistake in my answer where I wrote "-jar". I corrected it to "-cp". It works with "-cp" and I really tested it with "-cp".

Answer (score 2):

The class-path entry from a JAR file's manifest is **always** used to extend the classpath when loading classes from that JAR. It does not make a difference if you use the `-jar` switch or not.

I was in fact surprised about this behavior, but it is easily reproduced with a simple example using two classes A and B. Let A reference B. Put each class in its own JAR file. Add a manifest to A.jar that includes `Class-Path: B.jar`. Then the following command will correctly resolve B: `java -cp A.jar A`.

This is also described here [How the Java Launcher Finds JAR-class-path Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html) section *How the Java Launcher Finds JAR-class-path Classes*.

Comment: In my first version of the answer I wrote "java -jar A.jar A" which was of course wrong, because I want to point out that it works even without using "-jar". That mistake is now corrected.